# How to make emails supplied in a Text Field formatted as an email link in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a text based form, which enables anyone to type a text and at the same time supply an email in it and submit the form. Upon submitting the form, its show action should look like this image:

[image]

The code works for web links but emails supplied in the text are not formatted as email links and comes out as ordinary text. when I check the source code from browser, I see no html tag was added to the email supplied and it rendered as a text.

> How can I supply html tag to the emails supplied in this text field
>   such that the preview shows a real email address?

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @job do |f| %><br>
    <%= f.input :to_apply, label: 'How do people apply for this job?', placeholder: 'Example: Send a resume and cover letter to jobs@company.com.' %><br>
<% end %>
```

**model: job.rb**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :to_apply,
            presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sanitize` the text to remove any tags the user may have entered, scan for email addresses and replace with `gsub` and the `mail_to` helper, indicate the string is `html_safe` Build a helper method to do this...

```
class ApplicationController

  helper_method :mailify

  def mailify(text)
    new_text = text.to_s.dup.sanitize
    new_text.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i).each do |email|
      new_text.sub!(email, view_context.mail_to(email))
    end
    new_text.html_safe
  end

end
```

In your views...

```
<%= mailify(@job.to_apply) %>
```

Comment: This sounds more of it. Should I specify this code right on the `form template` or right on the `model file`?

Comment: Neither,  it should be a view helper. I'm travelling but I can update my answer to reflect this later today.  Or you can research rails helpers.

Comment: Okay, safe journey. I'll surely wait for you. Bear in mind this is for a job board where an employer supplies data for job post. I have updated my question to reflect model and form.

Comment: Ok, answer modified!

Comment: thanks so much. This worked. I like to be extra good, what should I read or learn the more?